# Qt in Ubuntu: Cannot compile using static boost libraries

Tags: qt, ubuntu, boost, static

I am trying to compile a C++ plugin using Ubuntu 14.04, Qt, and some boost libraries.

I built the boost libraries as follows:

```
libboost-all-dev
```

If I use shared boost libraries, e.g. libboost_system.so, the project compiles just fine. However, I want to compile using static boost libraries (libboost_system.a). I get the following error in my boost project:

```
 "relocation R_X86-64-32 against '.rodata.str1.1' cannot be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC".
```

This is my Qt project file:

```
VERSION = 1.3.1
TEMPLATE = lib
QT -= gui
CONFIG += warn_on plugin release 
CONFIG -= thread exceptions qt rtti debug 
CONFIG += c++11

INCLUDEPATH += /usr/include

LIBS += "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.a" 
LIBS += "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_filesystem.a"

DEFINES += APL=0 IBM=0 LIN=1 
DEFINES += IGOCONNECT_LIN_LIBRARY

TARGET = lin.xpl

QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -fvisibility=hidden 
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -fPIC

SOURCES += igoconnect_lin.cpp
HEADERS +=
unix {  
target.path = /usr/lib  
INSTALLS += target 
}
```

Anything I am doing wrong? Thank you so much!

Comment: what happens when you recompile with -fPIC like it says?

Comment: Thank you. Not sure what was meant: recompile the project or recompile the boost library. I tried to build the project with the following: `qmake /home/igor/Projects/igoconnect_lin/igoconnect_lin.pro -r -spec linux-g++ -fPIC`. It is not even starting to compile giving an immediate error. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Try that

```
LIBS += -lboost_system
```

Comment: It compiled! Let me check tomorrow if the plugin actually works in the program environment and I will accept the answer if everything is fine. In any case, many thanks!

Comment: Although I wonder whether this compiles libraries dynamically. Cheers.